# post data to the server using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This works for me

```
// default post header
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    // send login data
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'abc.php',
        data: $.param({
            email: "abc@gmail.com",
            password: "password"
        }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // handle success things
    }).catch(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // handle error things
    });
```

This does not

```
$http.post('abc.php', {email: "abc@gmail.com",
            password: "password"})
        .then(function(res){
            $scope.response = res.data; 
    })
```

Hi could you please elobrate why first implementation is working second doesn't. I'm very confused with short cut and long cut angular method
Thanks in advance

Comment: third parameter can be used for the config/header: `$http.post('abc.php', {email: "abc@gmail.com", password: "password"},{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})`

Comment: Well, the first one sends x-www-form-urlencoded data (i.e. the body looks like `email=abc@gmail.com&password=password`), whereas the second one sends JSON data (i.e. the body looks like `{"email":"abc@gmail.com","password":"password"}`). So, if the server expects the first one, sending the second one can't possibly work.

Comment: @JBNizet how to write second one to be correct

Comment: Just as you did in the first snippet, except you don't need jquery because angularjs has a service doing the equivalent of $.params: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, the problem lies with your server language of choice being unable to understand AngularJS’s transmission natively.

`$http.post` is transmitting your data as `Content-Type: application/json`

Change the header to URL Encoded as below :-

```
$http.post("abc.php", requestData, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
    transformRequest: transform
}).success(function(responseData) {
    //do stuff with response
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The second snippet should like this

```
$http.post('abc.php', {email: "abc@gmail.com",
            password: "password"})
    }).then(function(res){
            $scope.response = res.data;
 });
```